# Why swipe down gesture using touch move not detected in iPhone?

Tags: jquery, cordova

Hi I am developing a cross-platform mobile application using cordova. I need a action when a div is swiped down another div in top need to be appeared just like iPhone application search in home screen of iPhone. I have written the following code it do not work in my application.

```
function detectswipe(el,func) {
      swipe_det = new Object();
      swipe_det.sX = 0;
      swipe_det.sY = 0;
      swipe_det.eX = 0;
      swipe_det.eY = 0;
      var min_x = 20;  //min x swipe for horizontal swipe
      var max_x = 40;  //max x difference for vertical swipe
      var min_y = 10;  //min y swipe for vertical swipe
      var max_y = 10;  //max y difference for horizontal swipe
      var direc = "";
      ele = document.getElementById(el);
      ele.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e){
        var t = e.touches[0];
        swipe_det.sX = t.screenX; 
        swipe_det.sY = t.screenY;
      },false);
      ele.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var t = e.touches[0];
        swipe_det.eX = t.screenX; 
        swipe_det.eY = t.screenY;
        if ((((swipe_det.eX - min_x > swipe_det.sX) || (swipe_det.eX + min_x < swipe_det.sX)) && ((swipe_det.eY < swipe_det.sY + max_y) && (swipe_det.sY > swipe_det.eY - max_y)))) {
          if(swipe_det.eX > swipe_det.sX) direc = "r";
          else direc = "l";
        }
        //vertical detection
        if ((((swipe_det.eY - min_y > swipe_det.sY) || (swipe_det.eY + min_y < swipe_det.sY)) && ((swipe_det.eX < swipe_det.sX + max_x) && (swipe_det.sX > swipe_det.eX - max_x)))) {
          if(swipe_det.eY > swipe_det.sY) {calling();}
          else direc = "u";
        }

        if (direc != "") {
          if(typeof func == 'function') func(el,direc);
        }
        direc = "";
       // alert("touchmove");

      },false);

    }

    function myfunction(el,d) {
      //alert("you swiped on element with id '"+el+"' to "+d+" direction");
      if(d == "d")
        {
         //calling();

        }
    }



    detectswipe('swipemethod',myfunction);
     function calling()
  {
        $("#mydiv").removeClass("mydiv");
          $("#swipeinner").removeClass("swipeinner");
  }
```

This fiddle works fine in my mobile browser [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/anusibi/Lu9oks72/%22click%20here%22). But not in my application that is built in iPhone

I dont know the reason for it. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

For something not quite as heavyweight as jQuery mobile, try the hammer.js library.  It is less than 4k.  I use JQM, but that is a lot to pull in just to detect a swipe.

http://hammerjs.github.io